# Unity App Bar - Move open programs to the top?

Tags: unity

Im finally using Unity in Ubuntu 11.10. (yay!) I notice when I have some apps open, be it a PDF file, a doc file, a not commonly used app program, etc they are at the bottom of my Unity bar. Is there any way i can have all open apps appear at the top of my Unity bar? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

No, Unity opens programs in launcher where they are and everything else to the bottom of last launcher Icon. But you can move them manually. Just click and hold the icon in launcher and drag left out of launcher and drop in position on launcher you want.

Unless Canonical or somebody else does a work, it remains impossible AFAICS